# Adding MobFox to AdMob on Android

Tags: android, admob, mobfox

I am confused as to what is required here. I have signed up with MobFox and been approved, and I have added MobFox to my AdMob mediation, but MobFox says that it is not receiving any requests. Is there more that I have to do here.

MobFox has a tutorial on how to add AdMob as a secondary network, but that is not what I want to do. I also found instructions for what to do on iOS, but that did not seem to be particularly relevant.

I am wondering whether I just have to add the MobFox jar, and declare their intent in my manifest. That would make sense, if it could display its own ads on AdMob views. Nut it would be nice to hear from someone who has actually done this.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions and am not getting ads to appear via adMob mediation although in my case mobfox is getting the request and the ad listener is reporting that an ad was successfully received.

Make sure your manifest includes:

```
 <activity android:name="com.mobfox.sdk.InAppWebView"/>

<!--following is optional for full video ads -->
    <activity android:name="com.mobfox.video.sdk.MobFoxRichMediaActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

and make sure in admob, you have entered the correct publisher id. The following is a test id you can enter to see if you get live ads.

fed5ae7d80eb8378ddd8fd1b85e305ab

Again, I am not having success with mediating mobfox ads via admob but when I bypass admob, and add the mobfox ads directly to my layout, all works fine. I believe there is something wrong with their mediation jars but what do I know. I am about to use a custom event through admob and implement mobfox that way. I will let you know if it works.

Download the "regular" sdk from mobfox for banner ads and see if you can get ads using their sdk v1.5

The solution for me was to be sure to setLayoutParams on my adView to 320x50. Hope this helps you. Looks like there sdks work after all.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Your last paragraph was particularly interesting. I have noticed that Admob messes with the AdView something rotten. I have to define mine with a height of 50dp in order for it to display correctly, but AdMob then shrinks it to about 40px, making it almost illegible.

It is a pity that neither AmMob nor MobFox write anything meaningful in the logcat. It would be great if AdMob acknowledged that it had received a MobFox ad, and forwarded it to their InAppWebView activity. It would be equally nice if MobFox acknowledged that it had received an ad from AdMob.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Admob takes some time to update their data

Comment: You mean I just have to wait, and I do not have to change my app at all?

Comment: Look, open the app and leave it for a few minutes till the ad appears.
 Then in the admob website you will wait for a few hours till they update your status to"Active"

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand me. I want to add MobFox to AdMob, not the other way round.